# Pygame inflate not working

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm making a game using python and I'm looking to make a rectangle grow.

I saw on the pygame website that you use the inflate method and saw a demo of it and tried it but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
# defining statement
player = Rect(300, 100, 50, 50)
grow = player.inflate(100, 100)

# calling statement
if player.colliderect(food):
    foods.remove(food)
    grow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grow` is a variable, and it is not callable.

If you want to inflate the `player`, do this -

```
player = Rect(300, 100, 50, 50)

if player.colliderect(food):
            foods.remove(food)
            player = player.inflate(100, 100)
```

Comment: Hmm, i seam to get the same problem. I don't think my version of pygame supports it. I might need to find another way of making my rectangle grow.

Comment: I updated the code... Actually `player.inflate()` returns a rectangle itself. I guess it should work now.

Comment: Ayyy thanks so much dude. This helped me alot i am very new to python but again thanks!

Comment: Can you accept it as an answer if it worked for you?:)